Friend declaration for template class in C++
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
 public:
  template <typename U>
  friend class MyTemplateClass<U>;
};

int main() { return 0; }

The code provided above, tries to declare MyTemplateClass as a friend class to MyClass.
But, the issue arises when the compiler misinterprets it as specialization of template class MyTemplateClass which clearly, is not intended?
This works:
template <typename U>
friend class MyTemplateClass;

I do not understand why one would declare a type variable U, but would not use it in the friend declaration, If the purpose was to indicate that MyTemplateClass is a template class, then why can't we directly use this?
template <>
friend class MyTemplateClass;


This question is similar to: Class template with template class friend, what's really going on here?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


If the purpose was to indicate that MyTemplateClass is a template class, then why can't we directly use this?

In C++ template programming, when writing template <>, it's signaling that providing a specialization for some template. But, this case doesn't specify any specialization... is incomplete.
template <>
friend class MyTemplateClass;

However, when writing template <typename U>, it's informing the compiler that MyTemplateClass is a template class with one template parameter. So, this syntax works.
template <typename U>
friend class MyTemplateClass;


This is a syntax of a declaration of a partial template specialization (1):
  template <typename U>
  class MyTemplateClass<U>;

You used that syntax for the friend template specialization, hence from a compiler point of view, you intended to declare a template specialization that cannot appear without a prior template declaration or in another name scope.
This worked as you knew it (2):
  template <typename U>
  friend class MyTemplateClass;

You can only list template parameters without names in a required amount (3):
  template <typename>
  friend class MyTemplateClass;

This is a starting syntax of a full template specialization and also cannot be used without a prior template declaration, the same issue as seen in 1:
  template <>
  friend class MyTemplateClass;

You already knew a valid friend declaration in your question. It just can omit template parameter names, see 3, since they are not used.
